# A good documentation/tutorial for Excel PivotTables object model

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

Do you know of any good doc on Excel PivotTables object model ?
I have read "Excel 2007 Programmers reference", googled a bit, and found small bits here and there, but nothing global, coherent and complete.
Preferably for version < 2007, so I keep upwards compatibility when developing.
Thanks !

Comment: 7 months without an answer  ? c'mon guys :-)

Comment: I cannot offer any doc, but what I usually do under these circumstances is recording multiple macros using the function I like to automate to see what's done behind the scenes. As you can have a look into the recorded macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN is always a good resource to have, with examples most of the time. OZGrid.com is a great resource for many things Excel-VBA, including PivotTables.

- [OZGrid.com - Excel Pivot Tables](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-pivot-tables.htm)
- [MSDN PivotTable Object Model (Excel 2003)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174280%28office.11%29.aspx)